# jQuery undefined only in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, undefined, document.write

I am trying to figure out why the following code does not work in IE9.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>jQuery test</title>
   <script>
       document.write('<script src="jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
       document.write('<script>alert(jQuery);<\/script>');
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>jQuery test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Online demo: http://racino.pl/ie-behaviour/demo.html

I expect to see: alert with body of jQuery function:

```
function (e,t){return new v.fn.init(e,t,n)}
```

but in IE9 I see:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined
```

It works well in IE10 and latest FF31/Chrome37. 
Anyone know how to explain this?

I know some people consider document.write evil and there are other ways to do things but this question comes from curiosity and the need to maintain some hideous legacy code.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you including jquery.min with document write?

Comment: @BernardoLima one reason people do that is in fallback code for failed CDNs.

Comment: My assumption would be the jQuery file has not completed loaded; therefore you are getting the error saying it is undefined. The process of loading javascript files is probably faster in the other browsers.

Comment: @JoshMein the thing that makes it odd is that `<script>` tag processing is (supposed to be) synchronous.